# Games like Human Resource Machine?

Tags: programming, game, game-development

I have found [Human Resource Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_Resource_Machine) to be very helpful at teaching programming skills to a child with ADHD and some other issues and I'm hoping to find other games that are similar in design to teach real programming skills in a game-like format that's compatible with today's kids' expectations in learning.

For what it's worth, I have found that the same person that loves Human Resource Machine hates the sequel "Seven Billion Humans".

Any other games that are comparable to and as effective as Human Resource Machine?

Answer (score 0):

They seemed me to be suitable.

- [*Jump, Step, Step*](https://store.steampowered.com/app/575710/Jump_Step_Step/)
- [*Algo Bot*](https://store.steampowered.com/app/286300/Algo_Bot/)
- [*Among Start and Robots*](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1474840/Among_Stars_and_Robots/)

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried none of them >>> you will better wait other answers